# Stack could not be converted to int

Tags: php, oop

I have below code

```
public function account(Stack $volume) {
    //echo $volume->value();  //This line prints 300
    //echo $this -> balance(); //This line prints 400
    //echo gettype($volume -> value()); //int
    //echo gettype($this->balance());  //object
    echo $this -> balance() + $volume -> value(); // This line prints "Notice: Object of class Stack could not be converted to int"
}
```

Why it is happening like this ?

Comment: Just add `()` to clarify your logic.

Comment: Please provide the object as well?

Comment: It's probably trying to add $volume to the balance instead of the value from the $volume. Surrounding the accessor with parenthesis should fix your issue. I'd also recommend getting rid of the extra spaces in between, like the following: `($volume->value())`

Comment: Can you show a little bit of both `balance()` and `value()`. Also, what version of php are you on?

Comment: @JustinSchwimmer, `public function balance()
    {
        return $this->balance;
    }` and `public function value()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }` . and I am using `PHP Version 7.0.32`. Thanks.

Comment: @Snake14, Thanks you. Your solution is not working. I tried like this `echo ($this -> balance() + $volume -> value());`.Thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. The problem must be somewhere else. See https://3v4l.org/JWjHn

Comment: @Rei,I edited the question.

Comment: I see the results of the `gettype()` and that means you're trying to add an object to an int. That is an error. Are you expecting that it should not be an error?

Comment: Thanks @Rei, I would like to convert that `object` to `int`. What should I do to make it `int` ? Thanks.

Comment: You can use `strval()` followed by `intval()`. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the clues from these lines of your code:

```
//echo $this -> balance(); //This line prints 400
...
//echo gettype($this->balance());  //object
```

That means the object returned by `$this->balance()` can be converted to a string with a numeric value, which is `400` in your code.
To convert that to an int, you can use `strval()` followed by `intval()` like this:

```
echo intval(strval($this -> balance())) + $volume -> value();
```

Because the `+` operator can also work with numeric values in strings, just `strval()` will also work:

```
echo strval($this -> balance()) + $volume -> value();
```

The choice is yours.

Comment: Many Many Thanks  @Rei. Your solution is working like a Magic.

Comment: can you say what does it mean ? `(int) (string) $Account->balance() == 300`

Comment: @abuabu The `==` operator compares the left and right operands for equality. The left operand does the same thing as `intval(strval($Account->balance()))`.